# Limited data in elasticsearch search query in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a index named "twitter_profile_response_tms" in which I have doc type named as "posts"
In want to query all data in posts, i have total of 2636 data in posts but after running the query I only get 10 number of match data.

following is my query:

```
res = self.es.search(
            index="twitter_profile_response_tms",
            doc_type='posts',
            body={
                "query": {
                   "match": {
                   'username': 'wasimakramlive'
                }

            }
            },
        )
```

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can control it using `size` parameter. For e.g. to fetch 50 records set `"size": 50`.

```
res = self.es.search(
            index="twitter_profile_response_tms",
            doc_type='posts',
            body={
                "query": {
                   "match": {
                   'username': 'wasimakramlive'
                },
                "size": 50

            }
            },
        )
```

You can fetch data page wise as well using `from` and `size` parameters. Read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#paginate-search-results) more.

Comment: I want to get all matched, in some cases I don't know the size I cant define the size like this.

Comment: You can set it to a high number. Still if all equals to say 100000 records, would it make sense to get all the records in one go?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hits.total.values` key from the elasticsearch result payload to get the number of matching records.